# jss-rtl is not flipping styles, i.e. not flipping rule on the x-axis

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, right-to-left

I have a test application which is using Material UI.
I have RTL enabled on it
I have a margin left for my button on the application and when I use jss-rtl, I expect the margin to become margin-right which is not happening. It still remains as margin-left

The direction is passed to theme.js

```
const customizeTheme = (direction = "ltr") => {
  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    ...defaultThemeOptions,
    direction
  });
```

theme.js also has styles for button that should have flipped when direction is RTL

```
 contained: {
        color: "red",
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(4)
      }
```

But it does not.

The code is here

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-night-5uo4c?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

I know its bit late to answer this. But posting it, for those who lands here for answer

```
import { Theme } from '@material-ui/core';
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      margin: theme.spacing(4),
      border: "1px solid red"
    }
  })
);
const classes = useStyles();
.
.
.
<div className={classes.root}>
  {/* Content */}
  ...
  {/* End content */}
</div>
```